# Suicide became Selfdestruct, kill became destroy. What would be a good replacement for "mortal"?

Tags: solidity

Mortal is not a reserved word but it's a pretty explicit qualifier for contracts subject to self-destruction.

The change from `suicide`/`kill` to `selfdestruct`/`destroy` is a good initiative, but `mortal` kind of lost its meaning. What would be a good replacement ? I can't find anything satisfying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- recyclable
- destroyable
- terminable
- transient

I suggest if you use `destroy` then you should also use `destroyable`

Comment: Thank you, good suggestions ! I like recyclable, destroyable is straightforward but less imaginative. I'll leave the question open for more suggestion for a while before accepting it, I feel like there are more options.

Comment: `recycle()` was good if you consider that you got some Ether back, when calling it. But I think EIP150c eliminated the refund policy.